# Spring JPA Treat NULL fields as undefined and ignore them

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have an object that's being passed from some UI to my graphQL

```
class Person{
  String name;
String age;
String address;
}
```

This is a preexisting user, and I was sent the name and the address, but not the age. Can I tell JPA "Hey, if you see a NULL field, please do not overwrite it, just ignore it and update the other fields"

```
@GraphQLMutation(name = "createPerson")
    public List<Person> createPeople(@GraphQLArgument(name = "people") List<Person> people) {
        return personDao.saveAll(people);
    }

    @Repository
    public interface StrategyDAO extends JpaRepository<Strategy, Integer>{
@PleaseDontOverWriteNulls
void saveAll(List<Person>)
}
```

The annotation in my repository is representative of what would be great to have but which I haven't been able to find.